# how would save the output from playgames and print it? haskell

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

so I'm completely new to haskell and this is actually my first project after looking through the theory and I was just wondering how you could print the output of playgames in the main function - I've tried a couple of other ways but I get an error in nearly every attempt, thought it would be faster getting an answer through here.

```
main :: IO ()
main = do 
    let score = (0, 0)
    putStrLn "Please input total number of games."
    numGames <- readLn :: IO Int 
    putStrLn "Please input series of numbers for player 1 with no spaces."
    player1  <- readLn :: IO Int
    let lplayer1 =  listT player1 
    putStrLn "Please input series of numbers for player 2 with no spaces." 
    player2 <- readLn :: IO Int 
    let lplayer2 =  listT player2
    return $ play_games lplayer1 lplayer2 numGames score
    print lplayer1
    print lplayer2
    print score





play_games :: [Int] -> [Int] -> Int -> (Int, Int) -> (Int, Int)
play_games _ _ 0 score = score
play_games (x:xs) (d:dx) n (a, b) 
    | length xs > n-1 || length xs < n-1 = play_games xs dx 0 (a + b + 1 , 0)
    | length dx > n-1 || length dx < n-1 = play_games xs dx 0 (0 , a + b + 1)
    | x == 1 && d == 2 = play_games xs dx (n-1) (a + 1 , b) 
    | x == 2 && d == 1 = play_games xs dx (n-1) (a , b + 1) 
    | x == 2 && d == 0 = play_games xs dx (n-1) (a + 1 , b) 
    | x == 0 && d == 2 = play_games xs dx (n-1) (a , b + 1) 
    | x == 0 && d == 1 = play_games xs dx (n-1) (a + 1 , b) 
    | x == 1 && d == 0 = play_games xs dx (n-1) (a , b + 1) 
    | x == d = play_games xs dx (n-1) (a , b) 
    | otherwise = play_games xs dx (n-1) (a, b)



listT :: Int -> [Int]
listT 0 = []
listT num = listT (num `div` 10) ++ [num `mod` 10]
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: The reason why we want to you post the exact errors is because engaging with them helps you learn Haskell. Saying " I get an error" doesn't help anyone.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `return` with `print`:

```
print $ play_games lplayer1 lplayer2 numGames score
```